Pan like using data driven pages on a map view in ArcGIS Pro
I do a lot of extensive editing, and I found the data-driven pages and grid index feature very helpful in allowing me to pan to large areas in an organized and neat way. However, I recently switched to Pro and I am unable to locate a similar function. How can I do this?

Not doable anymore. Pages linked to layout only
